# Short Circuit Output Current - IC Definitions

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrated-circuit

What does "Short Circuit Output Current" mean? Does it mean that the voltage output will be to 0V at this specified current? So what would be the maximum current sourced without having a large impact on the voltage output? There is no graphic, it would be nice to have the voltage output in function of the load!

[image]

Here is the datasheet: https://datasheet.octopart.com/FAN4174IS5X-Fairchild-Semiconductor-datasheet-8824583.pdf

Thank you very much and have a nice day!

Comment: Jess sorry but you made an error in judgement.

Comment: I let the community decide what would be the corrrect answer if my judgement is bad :)

Comment: @Jess would it be possible to sacrifice an opamp and test out the short to rails conditions and output current? I'm guessing it's better than having a problem after building the pcb...

Comment: @Jess output may not have cmos. Please see my edited answer below.

Comment: I will find an other solution ;) But you can do it if you want :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are Rail-to-Rail I/O, CMOS Amplifiers.

Datasheet indicates Vs=5V. In this context, short-circuit implies operating the CMOS FET outputs with RdsOn at any output voltage rail to rail.

Thus +/-33 mA means RdsOn = 5V/33mA = 150 Ohms typical equivalent resistance.  This affects the output rise time for step pulses into a know C load.  However when not shorted, Zout is reduced by feedback gain in linear mode.

added:

- Under different conditions the table also says;
- RL=10k to Vs/2 (for Vs=5V)  Vo= 0.01 to 4.99V   I=250uA, thus RdsOn=40
- RL=1k to Vs/2 (for Vs=5V)  Vo= 0.10 to 4.90V    I=2.5mA  thus RdsOn=40

[proof by Simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000005%2035.60246606707791%2050%205%2043%0Ar%20-32%20-48%20176%20-48%200%2010000%0Aw%20176%20-48%20176%2064%200%0Aa%20-32%2064%2080%2064%209%205%200%201000000%200.29600019557269475%200.2960290562440053%20100000%0Af%2080%2032%20144%2032%2033%201.25%200.007200000000000001%0Af%2080%2096%20144%2096%2032%201.25%200.0066%0Aw%20144%2048%20144%2064%200%0Aw%20144%2064%20144%2080%201%0Aw%20144%2064%20176%2064%203%0Ag%20144%20112%20144%20144%200%0AR%20144%2016%20144%20-32%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%2080%2032%2080%2064%200%0Aw%2080%2064%2080%2096%200%0Aw%20-32%20-48%20-32%2048%200%0AR%20-32%2080%20-80%2080%200%203%2040%202.5%202.5%200%200.5%0Ar%20176%2064%20272%2064%200%2010000%0AR%20272%2064%20272%2048%200%200%2040%202.5%200%200%200.5%0As%20176%20-48%20240%20-48%200%201%20true%0Ag%20240%20-48%20240%20-32%200%0Ab%20-16%200%20156%20135%200%0A403%20288%2016%20416%2080%200%201_64_0_4354_5_0.1_0_2_1_3%0Ax%20190%20-65%20252%20-62%204%2024%2050%5CsmA%0A403%20288%2096%20416%20160%200%207_64_0_12545_0.0001_0.0002490756427092177_0_2_7_3%0Ax%20330%20-67%20381%20-64%204%208%20T.%5CsStewart%5CsEE'75%0A38%200%200%201%20101%20Resistance%0A)

Using KVL as follows;

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhJLYw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Only in 3.6V logic do they make lower RdsOn =25 Ohms +/50% in order to shoot-thru and yet have high speed.

Comment: Rail to rail does not mean output mosfet will not get damaged at higher output current. Output mosfet Rdson seems to be about 0.3 Ohms (0.01 V / 0.033 A), so output short to ground can lead to 16 Amps through the mosfet.

Comment: @Indraneel  Impossible to get 0.3Ohms Do you understand where you made a big error?  Double check.

Comment: Datasheet specifies rail to rail output up to 10 mV from the rails. The max current that can be sourced or drained is 33 mA. Assuming this is all in the output mosfet, which is not an unreasonable assumption, we can apply ohms law and arrive at 0.3 ohms. Am I wrong or was something not clear? I do not understand where I made a big error, like you say. Can you please explain?

Comment: With a 150 ohms Rdson, there will be a 5V drop across the mosfet at 33 mA. Which means output will be zero volts, no matter what signal you input into the opamp. Is this what you want your opamp to do?

Comment: The Rdson of 150 ohms for the output mosfet that you have calculated is hopelessly inaccurate and misleading. Delete your answer as it may lead to unsafe operation and potentially start a fire if there is no output current limiter in the circuit.

Comment: I am with this answer rather than the one which states that IC can output 16 A and also 0.3 ohms output resistance.

Comment: @muyustan IC cannot output 16A for more than a few microseconds before burning up. That is exactly what will happen if output current is not limited and input is not within range. Like I said, 0.3 ohms Rdson is best case scenario, in reality it is probably about 1 ohm.

Comment: @Indraneel please tell me what will be the situation if the IC is supplied with +5V and output is shorted to ground?

Comment: @muyustan IC will burn up because more than 33 mA will flow through output mosfet. This may or may not depend on the input signal voltage.

Answer (score 3):

> What does " Short Circuit Output Current " mean ? Does it mean that the voltage output will be to 0V at this specified current ?

It means that with the output shorted to VS or GND, the maximum current will be limited to 33 mA.

> So what would be the maximum current sourced without having a large impact on the voltage output ?

The Output Voltage Swing show you that : not comprehensively, but maybe there's a graph elsewhere in the datasheet giving more detail. (*)

It shows you the output voltage into two different resistor values, reflecting a light load ( 10 kilohms) and a heavier load (1 kilohm). You will typically lose 10 mV driving 2.5 V into 10 kilohms, (0.25 mA) or 100 mV driving 2.5 V into 1 kilohm (2.5 mA).

Thus if 0.1V meets your definition of "not a large impact on the voltage output" you can drive 2.5 mA output current.

The implication of showing 10K and 1K and not, say, 500R or 100R, is that if you need the full voltage at higher output currents, this is probably the wrong opamp for the job.

(*) maybe there's a graph elsewhere in the datasheet giving more detail.

There is : Figure 14, which appears considerably more pessimistic than the actual spec, at 2.7Vp-p for 10 kilohm load. I do not know which of these is accurate. That's what testing, and talking to FAEs is for.

Answer (score 0):

It does not say short circuit to ground, or +Vcc anywhere. So voltage is whatever that will lead to source *or drain* of 33 mA. Since it is not specified "short circuit" to what, a better term would be "max output current". Also see page 9 of the datasheet on how to add an output series resistor to prevent overload.

**edit**: datasheet does not say that *outputs* have mosfets, so the entire discussion below may be redundant. With bjt output, the opamp likely has the conventional current limiting design... and the datasheet may simply have forgotten to specify the short circuit as continuous short circuit to ground. However, I am retaining it, just in case it does have mosfets in the output stage (which is very unlikely for a low cost opamp)

Output mosfet Rdson seems to be 0.3 Ohms (0.01 V / 0.033 A). Thus short circuit to ground at 5V supply will lead to 16 A through the output mosfet. This will probably also depend on the input signal. Fig 14 only specifies input up to 2 V. Simultaneous rail to rail input and a continuous output short circuit will probably damage the mosfet.

Comment: So if I have a load equal to 220 Ohm under 5V it will works as it is inferior to 33 mA ? It is used for make a clk signal. At least to transform 3V3 clk signal into 5V clk signal

Comment: I think so, although keeping below 20 mA may be better as that is what the datasheet seems to be doing. That means 250 Ohm. Make sure you also check the input pin specification of microcontroller.

Comment: What do you mean by the input pin specification ? "No" current will be drawn by the op amp inputs.

Comment: @Jess that is the ideal case, not the practical.

Comment: how did you end up with 0.01 V / 0.033 A equation? Can you show it a bit more detailed?

Comment: Who accepted this hopelessly inaccurate answer?

Comment: Author ought to correct or delete this

Comment: @Jess I said input pin specification of microcontroller... which means input pin of the microcontroller... not the op amp. the output resistor to op-amp needs to be chosen so as not to deliver more current and damage the input pin of the microcontroller. I'm assuming the OP wants to feed opamp output to a microcontroller.

Comment: @muyustan From the datasheet (1st page) "■ Output swing to within 10mV of either rail". and also from the extract of datasheet posted by OP, the max output current allowed is 33 mA. The 10 mV drop can reasonably be assumed to be in the output mosfet. Applying ohm's law we arrive at an effective resistance of 0.3 ohms for the output mosfet. This is likely a best case scenario. In reality the mosfet resistance is probably higher, since 10 mV specification is probably at lower output current.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 obviously the OP accepted the answer since only he/she can, and I still think I am correct. Could you be somewhat more specific about why I aught to correct or delete this? And what to correct, if you think I should correct something? Your comments are rather cryptic, and currently, not really adding any useful information.

Comment: OK Your analysis is incorrect. "Output mosfet Rdson seems to be 0.3 Ohms (0.01 V / 0.033 A)."   But you are conflating 10mV and 33mA from different test conditions.   RdsOn = 5V/33mA = 150 Ohms with full scale short.  The other items are for Vs/2 linear operation.  drop 1mV@ 2.5V/10k and 10mV @ 2.5V/1k

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 If your Rdson is 150 ohms, then resistance will have to be even higher during linear operation. Check your calculations again. As shown in datasheet, opamp maintains linearity at 20 mA output. Even the datasheet has typo in figure 14 which shows this. Rdson for the mosfet can never exceed 15 ohms, and is very likely somewhere near 1 ohms to ensure proper linear operation. Datasheet never mentions 33 mA is full scale short... it is purely your assumption.

Comment: @Indraneel you made 2 more errors above.  a) Table in question says Isc = +/- 33mA typ. which is for Vs=5V and +/- means  full scale short to either rail.   That is not my assumption.  b) 5V / 0.3 Ohms = 16.7 Amps !.  c) My simulation and equations match perfectly.  Last update